# Gradle dependency with transitive false continue to retrieve dependency

Tags: java, gradle

I have a build with a dependency declared this way

```
compile ("org:module:+"){
    changing=true
    transitive=false
}
```

but even if the transitive is false i still found some dependencies packages inside my build. In the build output with debug option turned on i find this messages

```
[org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder] Visiting dependency org:module:1.21(compile) -> commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.8.0(compile,runtime)
12:19:32.773 [DEBUG] [io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.DependencyManagementPlugin] Processing dependency 'commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.8.0'
12:19:32.774 [DEBUG] [io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.DependencyManagementPlugin] No dependency management for dependency 'commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.8.0'
12:19:32.774 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder] Selecting new module version commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.8.0
```

and much more about other module dependencies. What I have to do to force to explicitly NOT retrieve this packages?

Comment: What is your gradle version ? Maybe transitive flag is overrided after in your build script ?

Comment: No i found the solution and it was really hard to find, it was a package inside another package that has transitive true, so even if I had the idea that my project was retrieving the packages that packages was taken inside project by other packages dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already found out, it was another dependency which had the same transitive dependency. However this should not be hard to find. You can run Gradle built-in task `dependencies` to get a tree view of all your dependencies.

Just for completeness, you can exclude all unwanted dependencies by:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.example', module: 'dep'
}
```